# How to swap position of href attributes with each other after one of those is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a language switch, which contains 2 languages.

In it's current its not clear what language is currently selected so I want to swap the 2 a href attributes with each other so that becomes more clear.

Could someone tell me which selectors I have to use to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="language-holder">
     <div class="language-select">
           <a class="eng" href="#">English</a>
             <ul>
                   <li><a class="du" href="#">Dutch</a></li>
             </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.language-select a').click(function() {
      var parent = $(this);

      if ($(this).hasClass('eng')) {
      }
      else if($(this).hasClass('du')){
       }
});
```

Comment: why would you switch the same href??

Comment: Your markup with the links in- and outside the `ul` is strange. Just keep one link for each language for the sake of usability. Mark the active language bold or similar to indicate, which language is selected.

Comment: You could add a `current` class... Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/QwCF9/

Comment: No, I ment to switch the position of the href, for example when you click the href inside the li it switches position with the href above

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class `current` and assign it to the most recently clicked element.

```
$('.language-select').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Sud/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may swap class and href both

```
$('.language-select a').click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('eng')) {
          $(this).removeClass('eng').addClass('du').attr('href',$('.language-select a[class="du"]').attr('href'));
      }
      else if($(this).hasClass('du')){
           $(this).removeClass('du').addClass('eng').attr('href',$('.language-select a[class="eng"]').attr('href'));
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
$('li a').click(function() {
      var clone = this;
      var top = $('.language-select a');
      $('.language-select').remove(top);
      $('.language-select').append(clone);
      $('li a').remove(clone);
      $('li a').append(top);
});
```